# Unable to apply Merge function to convert to get Set on a Stream output

Tags: java, java-stream, hashset, collectors

Here is a sample source data structure to simplify the problem case data for my scenario.
This Map has duplicate descriptions for different codes.

```java
Map<Integer, String> descriptionsByCode = new HashMap();
descriptionsByCode.put(1, "description 1");
descriptionsByCode.put(2, "description 2");
descriptionsByCode.put(4, "description 3");
descriptionsByCode.put(5, "description 4");
descriptionsByCode.put(6, "description 5");
descriptionsByCode.put(7, "description 5");
descriptionsByCode.put(8, "description 5");
descriptionsByCode.put(9, "description 2");
descriptionsByCode.put(10, "description 2");
descriptionsByCode.put(11, "description 3");
descriptionsByCode.put(12, "description 4");
descriptionsByCode.put(13, "description 1");
descriptionsByCode.put(14, "description 6");
descriptionsByCode.put(15, "description 8");
```

I also have a complex business object, but for simplicity purpose lets assume there is an object with only 2 field.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class StatusCounts {
    private String description;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> someIemCountByStatusCode; //defaults to zero for our example
}
```

If, I want to have a map of `StatusCount` object By Description.
I can have it easily. Below is a working code, added here to concentrate on the main problem mentioned after this

```
     Map<String, StatusCounts> statusCountsByDescription
            = descriptionsByCode
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getValue(),  //key function
                    e -> new StatusCounts(e.getValue(),   //value function 
                            Collections.singletonMap(e.getKey(), 0)),
                    (e, v) ->  // merge function for collision 
                    { // is there a better way to write below code ? 
                        Map m = new HashMap();
                        m.putAll(e.getItemCountByStatusCode());
                        m.putAll(v.getItemCountByStatusCode());
                        e.setItemCountByStatusCode(m);
                        return e;
                    }
            ));
```

Above code is not clean, but working well.
What I actually want is, a Set instead of Map

I am unable to find a way, in `reduce` or `collect` functions, to provide a handling for `collision detection` (like merge function does in case of `Collectors.toMap`).

The combiner function in both reduce or collect, doesn't work for collision.
`Collectors.toSet` doesn't even accept any parameter.
So I though I can write collision detection handling in `accumulator` in case of `reduce` or in or `Biconsumer` in case of `collect`. So I tried below using `collect` & `BiConsumer`
But this one is uncompilable same is happening with `reduce`

```
Set<StatusCounts> statusCounts
            = descriptionsByCode
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(() -> new HashSet<StatusCounts>(),
                    (set, entry) -> {
                        Optional<StatusCounts> statusCount
                                = findStatusCountWithSameDescription(set, entry.getValue());

                        if (statusCount.isPresent()) {
                            statusCount.get()
                                        .getItemCountByStatusCode()
                                        .put(entry.getKey(), 0);
                        } else {
                            set.add(new StatusCounts(
                                    entry.getValue(),
                                    Collections.singletonMap(entry.getKey(), 0)));
                        }
                        return set;
                    }
            );



private static Optional<StatusCounts> findStatusCountWithSameDescription
       (HashSet<StatusCounts> set, String description) {
        return set.stream()
                  .filter(e -> e.getDescription()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(description))
                  .findFirst();
    }
```

This is the compilation error

```
Cannot resolve method 'collect(<lambda expression>, <lambda expression>)'
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get a Set of status codes for each description?

Comment: As the compilation error says, there is no `collect` method with two parameters. There is a method with one parameters and a method with three parameters. Performing a linear search through the set for each element in the accumulator function is one of the worst things someone could come up with, anyway.

Comment: @Holger I agree with your linear search comment. 
For background, this is a change in existing code, Input is fixed as `Map<Integer, String>` and new calling code requires a `Set<ComplexObject>`.  
I'm now allowed to change any of those.
I can write this code in imperative way. but couldn't figure out by stream pipeline. You already said no `Stream::collect`  method with 2 parameter. 
I added a sample code to depict what I expect, not a working code.  
I believe my main question is "how to have a `Collision resolution strategy` when collecting into `Set`" ?

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Comment: Answer is sort of wrong and uncompilable even when I provided the whole sample code... But it gives a direction to use 2 pipelines. I already upvoted it... Let me check more and maybe I'll update the working solution in question

Comment: In my previous comment there is a typo I meant " I'm NOT  allowed to change any of those" I typed now instead of not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have used `Collectors.groupingBy` to solve this:

```java
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map 
    = descMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, 
                                            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Here, a map would be generated with the description as the key. `Collectors.mapping` maps each entry to the status code and then combines them into a `Set`

I think that a `Set<Integer>` instead of `Map<Integer, Integer>` would have been sufficient within the `StatusCounts` class. This is because from the code, it seems like you just want to know the different codes under a description. In that case you could try the below:

```java
return map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(entry -> new StatusCounts(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

### **UPDATE**

If you are not allowed to change the existing `StatusCounts` class, then you could try the below:

```java
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> tempMap
    = descMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, 
                                            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 0))));

// You may combine the below code with above instead of using a tempMap.
// I have separated it for simplicity
Set<StatusCounts> result 
    = tempMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .map(entry -> new StatusCounts(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I can not accept this as answer because our output is not exactly what I asked in question. I need a `Set<StatusCounts>` .  your constructor is also incorrect.
But I upvoted the answer, because the first pipeline can be used to get the collision detection and I can try another pipeline to get the required result

Comment: @ThrowableException Is the `Map` within `StatusCounts` really necessary. `Set` would be sufficient. From the code you have posted, it seems like the value part of each entry in that map would always be `0`. That is why I thought of changing the constructor part such that the class would contain `String` and `Set<Integer>`  instead of `String` and `Map<Integer, Integer>`. If you are not allowed to make updates to that class then okay. But it would have been better if you had mentioned such a restriction in the question itself rather than in the comment. Anyways, updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: I actually solved this with a custom collector in the first pipeline returning set..
So instead of two pipelines, I've one...I'll post the answer soon. To post here I've to modify the code from my actual business objects to the Objects I used here. 
But I accepted your updated answer as this solves the problem stated in the question and upvoted the comment. However, I clearly provided the objects in the questions One can not change the quesiton itself to come to an answer. Surely one can provide recommendations but can not simply change the condition in question and provide an answer.